# Test REST Get WS with RESTClient : FromBody always null

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, rest-client

This is my Ws :

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/Schema/convertDwgEnJson")]
public IHttpActionResult Get([FromBody]string filePath)
{
    //TODO

    return Ok("blah");
}
```

I try to test it with FireFox addOn RestClient, choosing GET, with the good url, and in body i have "test", so my filePath param should contains "test", but it's always null.
Where's the problem?

Comment: A get request does not have a Body

Comment: Show the raw request being sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GET requests do not have a body so you need to remove the `[FromBody]` attribute

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/Schema/convertDwgEnJson")]
public IHttpActionResult Get(string filePath)
{
    //TODO

    return Ok("blah");
}
```

You need to include it in the url if you are doing a GET

```
api/Schema/convertDwgEnJson?filePath=test
```

If you need to send it in the Body then You need to do a POST or PUT request.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/Schema/convertDwgEnJson")]
public IHttpActionResult Post(string filePath)
{
    //TODO

    return Ok("blah");
}
```

Comment: I need to pass a filePath, so i would like to avoid passing it though the URL

Comment: Then you should do a POST

Comment: A POST should be used to provide data, like to save a new customer in database, that's not what my WS will do, it will respond with some data.

Comment: then what you want is a GET, but in a GET, the body is ignored on the server by design specifications